# centos which file to edit to get .bash_profile running?

Tags: bash, centos, profile

I want to know which file to edit in order to launch my `.bash_profile` when I graphically start the terminal.

---

I am using an AWS Workspace with the following OS and the default MATE terminal.

```bsh
$ cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

There are so many files in `~/etc`:

```
bashrc
profile
/profile.d
    #lots of .sh
```

But in my `/home/<usr>` directory I have:

```
.bashrc
.bash_profile
```

^ I created this bash_profile file and it works when I launch the terminal graphically and do `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

---

**REQUESTED EDIT:**
This is what I am putting in my `.bash_profile` it colors my command prompt on every line and adds a timestamp and mentions the virtualenv I have active. I expect it to

```bsh
# in order to be able to change the color of venv prompt
#
function virtualenv_info(){
    # Get Virtual Env
    if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]; then
        # Strip out the path and just leave the env name
        venv="${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/}"
    else
        # In case you don't have one activated
        venv=''
    fi
    [[ -n "$venv" ]] && echo "(pvenv:$venv) "
}

# disable the default virtualenv prompt change
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1

VENV="\$(virtualenv_info)";
#

git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/<b:\1>/'
}

# set the prompt color
# color starts with `\e[36m` and is closed with `\e[0m`
export PS1="\e[36m[\t] \e[38;5;203m${VENV}\e[38;5;78m\$(git_branch) \e[38;5;179m\w \e[0m☯  "
```

[image]

---

**WORKAROUND** by checking this box in the default MATE terminal application.

[image: REQUESTED EDIT:]

Comment: What graphical terminal program are you launching? Whichever one it is, you could try configuring it to launch the Bash shell with `--login` option which causes Bash to read your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` files (in that order).

Comment: MATE terminal. Thank you. I will look for that option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what sort of things you have added to `~/.bash_profile` and when you need them to be sourced. The simple answer is that you probably want to be using `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`, but the details will depend on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @celadon not quite. When launched as a login shell, bash will read `/etc/profile` and then it will _only_ read the _first_ of those files. So if `~/.bash_profile` exists, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` will be ignored. From the INVOCATION section of `man bash`: "*After  reading [/etc/profile], it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that exists  and  is  readable.*"

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax my answer here might be helpful: [Scripts in /etc/profile.d Being Ignored?](//askubuntu.com/a/438170)

Comment: [When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/717014)

Comment: Please don't do that. You don't want to change the behavior of all shells, just use the appropriate file as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use profile for this. Instead, add your changes to `~/.bashrc`. That's the file most commonly used for this sort of thing which you want evaluated for each shell you open.

So, just remove your modifications from `~/.profile` and add them to `~/.bashrc` instead. For more details on which files are read under what circumstances, see this answer on our sister site, Ask Ubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/a/438170

Comment: So, I thought the whole point of creating a `.bash_profile` was so that you don't mess with the defaults in `.bashrc`. Is that not the case?

Comment: That being said. I have done this and it is working.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax no, not at all. `~/.bash_profile`  (and `~/.profile`) and `~/.bashrc` are all there for each user to play with. You are supposed to mess with them, the ones you shouldn't mess with unless you know what you're doing are `/etc/bash.bashrc` (sometimes also called `/etc/bashrc`) and `/etc/profile`. Anything in your `~/` is there for you to edit. It's just that the normal file to edit for this sort of thing is `~/.bashrc` and not `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Exactly and don't forget to check for an interactive session!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your graphical environment (LXDM, XFCE, KDE, etc). 
Some of them don't source `~/.bash_profile`.

If you have your reason to use it (e.g. compatibility reasons), you can source it in your `~/.bashrc` (expecting you are using `bash` as your default shell).

```
echo "source ~/.bash_profile" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This method comes with some disadvantages.

- It will only be sourced by interactive login shells.
- Other graphical programs won't have the same environment.

I would recommend to use something which works natively with your setup.

1. Use `/etc/profile`

   - It's global.
   - Affects all user.
   - Disadvantage: It can be overriden more easily because it is sourced very early (but never experienced this in reality. But some desktop environments or something similar set their own unique environment and override the *old*).
2. Checkout the behaviour of your desktop environment. LXDM for example will source the following (and not `~/.bash_profile`):

   ```
   /etc/profile
   ~/.profile
   /etc/xprofile
   ~/.xprofile
   ```

References:

- [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)
- Great context information linked by @terdon: [Scripts in /etc/profile.d Being Ignored?](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170)

**EDIT:**

In response to your edit: As expected, mate doesn't source `~/bash_profile` by default.

Some stuff about design decisions (because you asked it in you latest comment).
Typically you only set environment variables in your `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` etc why I would consider to move your script else where and not in the `~/.bashrc`.

What you are doing is very shell specific. It's reasonable to put it in your `~/.bashrc`.

If you are using more shells than one, you could split it into different files. For example define your `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` inside a environment file like `/etc/profile`, create a new bash script with the function `virtualenv_info()` and only source the script in the shell environment where you need it. This would be a clean solution but it will work if you only put the whole script into your `~/.bashrc`.